# dict not returning all items in python

Tags: python, function, csv, dictionary

Long story short. Im trying to pass my dictionary to a new function. Currently the return is printing one row of data when called.

```
import csv

def csvRead():
    with open('data.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
        rcsv = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
        mydict = {}

    for line in rcsv:
        for k, v in line.items():
            mydict[k] = float(v)*2
            print(mydict.items())
    return mydict.items()


print('current: ', csvRead())
```

Im not entirely sure why this is happening.

the output is

```
dict_items([('Velocity', 2.2)])
dict_items([('Speed', 111.0)])
dict_items([('Acceleration', 44.4)])
dict_items([('Velocity', 6.6)])
dict_items([('Speed', 8.8)])
dict_items([('Acceleration', 13.2)])
Current: dict_items([('Velocity', 6.6), ('Speed', 8.8), ('Acceleration', 13.2)]}
```

The goal here is to avoid pandas.

CSV is formatted as so

```
Velocity,Speed,Acceleration
1.1,55.5,22.2
3.3,4.4,5.5
8.8,9.9,5.5
```

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: why you have newline as ' '?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in the dict. In your `mydict` the keys are the field names from the csv file, thus each row values update the dict and at the end of the loop only the values from the last row are present in the dict.

Comment: Notwithstanding the issues already addressed, your CSV file is broken. You have 3 columns yet the first data line has 4 values whereas the others have 3

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you are overwriting your dict values.
I implemented it now in a way, in which your dict is initialized with empty lists as values and the read data is appended to these lists:

```
mydict = {key: [] for key in rcsv.fieldnames}
for line in rcsv:
        for k, v in line.items():
            mydict[k].append(float(v)*2) # <-- you were overwriting the value in each loop
            print(mydict.items())
```